# sorted() fails on the very first call only

Tags: python

I'm using python 3.7.4. The data I'm trying to sort is in a series of csv files with the format '1234_5678.A.csv','1234_5678.B.csv','1234_5678.C.csv','1234_5678.D.csv', etc..

Code is as follows:

```
import sys
## GET ALL CSV Files in a folder
import os
import glob

def filter_name(filterString, fileNames):
    filtered = []
    for name in fileNames:
        if filterString in name:
            filtered.append(name)
    return filtered

def sort_key(fileName):
    """Assumes file name of 12345_9876.A.csv structure
    returns 9876 value"""
    _, backhalf = fileName.split("_")
    return backhalf.split(".")[0]

file_path=r'C:\\Auto\\201907 compare\\AEG data\\#1022206 abcdef879 S1 - doneagain\\orig - Copy\\'
path = file_path
extension = 'csv'
#os.chdir(path)  # TODO This might be causing more problems than just the image packing thing...
listOfFiles = [i for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.{}').format(extension))]

listOfFiles = ['C:\\Auto\\201907 compare\\AEG data\\#1022206 abcdef879 S1 - doneagain\\orig - Copy\\20190531_155638064567.A.csv',
'C:\\Auto\\201907 compare\\AEG data\\#1022206 abcdef879 S1 - doneagain\\orig - Copy\\20170532_155646505788.B.csv',
'C:\\Auto\\201907 compare\\AEG data\\#1022206 abcdef879 S1 - doneagain\\orig - Copy\\20170532_155654944787.C.csv',
'C:\\Auto\\201907 compare\\AEG data\\#1022206 abcdef879 S1 - doneagain\\orig - Copy\\20170532_155703390027.D.csv',
'C:\\Auto\\201907 compare\\AEG data\\#1022206 abcdef879 S1 - doneagain\\orig - Copy\\20170532_155901884437.A.csv',
'C:\\Auto\\201907 compare\\AEG data\\#1022206 abcdef879 S1 - doneagain\\orig - Copy\\20170532_155910324109.B.csv',
'C:\\Auto\\201907 compare\\AEG data\\#1022206 abcdef879 S1 - doneagain\\orig - Copy\\20170532_155918771536.C.csv',
'C:\\Auto\\201907 compare\\AEG data\\#1022206 abcdef879 S1 - doneagain\\orig - Copy\\20170532_155927211990.D.csv']


###listOfFiles = ['20170532_155638064567.A.csv', '20190732_155646505788.B.csv', '20190732_155654944787.C.csv', '20190732_155703390027.D.csv', '20170532_155901884437.A.csv', '20170532_155910324109.B.csv', '20190732_155918771536.C.csv', '20190732_155927211990.D.csv']

Afilenames = sorted(filter_name("A", listOfFiles), key=sort_key)
Bfilenames = sorted(filter_name("B", listOfFiles), key=sort_key)
Cfilenames = sorted(filter_name("C", listOfFiles), key=sort_key)
Dfilenames = sorted(filter_name("D", listOfFiles), key=sort_key)




print("# Of Files: \n")
print(len(listOfFiles))
print("List Of Files: \n")
print(listOfFiles)

print("# Of A Files: \n")
print(len(Afilenames))
print("# Of B Files: \n")
print(len(Bfilenames))
print("# Of C Files: \n")
print(len(Cfilenames))
print("# Of D Files: \n")
print(len(Dfilenames))
```

The output of the print statements is incorrect.

```
Total files = 8
Total A files = 8 
Total B files = 2
```

This is a bizarre problem..any hints?

Comment: *"The output"*.  Which output is that?

Comment: Can you build a [mre] that acts as a **standalone** reproducer -- that is to say, one that doesn't need to have the same files you have on disk to see the problem, or allow a fix to be tested? (Similarly, to be testable, we need to have *specific* actual and expected outputs; beyond Stephen's request for the above, it's also part of the MRE definition, and thus required by site rules as/where appropriate to make a question answerable).

Comment: output of the print statements.

Comment: @DNR, yes, that's obvious, but you're the only person who has the files that this globs over on disk, so nobody but you can run this code to know what the print statements *actually output*. If you're asking someone else to create those files -- frankly, that's an unreasonable request. Ideally, code should be isolated enough to be able to run in a sandboxed online interpreter like http://ideone.com/ so nobody needs to risk their own machine in the process of helping others.

Comment: ...so, if you can hardcode a list of files in the code itself and still have the problem, *do that*. (Similarly, if you can leave out the `sort_key` function and still have the problem, do that too; the goal is to cut down to the *shortest possible thing* that demonstrates a specific issue, narrow issue; and the more code you cut out, the narrower and more specific your question becomes).

Comment: @ShadowRanger: In the sorted function I'm looking for 'A', 'B', 'C' or 'D'. This line: listOfFiles = [i for i in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.{}').format(extension))] returns all the csv files in the folder... glob is only looking at extension='csv'. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your `filter_name` function allows the `filterString` anywhere in the name, and the names returned by `glob` aren't just the file name alone, but the complete path to the file.

Your paths all include a capital `A` (in the directories `Auto` and `AEG data`), and they all include `C` (the drive letter), so they *all* pass the filter for `A` and `C` (neither `B` nor `D` appears in the path outside the final file name, so they're filtered as you expect).

If you want to filter based on the name alone, not the full path, strip off the path for the purposes of the test:

```
def filter_name(filterString, fileNames):
    filtered = []
    for name in fileNames:
        if filterString in os.path.basename(name):  # basename removes the rest of the path
            filtered.append(name)
    return filtered
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thanks!